# What is a simple cross-platform way is determining processor architecture using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I need to know whether a machine has 64bit or 32bit processor, what is the simplest, native and cross-platform way of doing this in PowerShell without complex workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is probably:

```
[System.Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem
```